# How to run a single test/simulation with Gatling Maven plugin?

Tags: maven, gatling, maven-gatling-plugin

Is it possiblt to run only a single test/simulation with Gatling Maven plugin with comand line arguments? Similar to SBT plugin `testOnly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with parameter `gatling.simulationClass`, for example

```
mvn gatling:test -Dgatling.simulationClass=foo.bar.MySimulation
```

(Gatling Maven plugin 3.1.1 used)

In general, different parameters can be seen with

```
mvn gatling:help -Ddetail=true
```